# Finding all records within a date range in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not sure why my syntax isn't working, but I'm looking for all records where the field Pend_Start_Dt is greater than my variable PndStDt and Pend_End_Date is less than my variable PndEnDt.  If the record has no current end date, then it should pull that too, as long as the start date is between the start and end date the user enters.

So, basically, there's 2 scenarios where the record should be included:

The Start Date field is greater than or equal to the start date the user enters **and** the End Date field is less than or equal to the end date the user enters

or

the Start Date field is between the start date and end date the user enters **and** the End Date field is null.

I hope that's not too confusing.

The syntax I tried is below, but my stored procedure won't compile.

```
Where a.Audit_Status = '3' 
AND ((a.Pend_Start_DT >= TO_DATE (PndStDt, 'yyyy/mm/dd')) AND (a.Pend_End_DT <= (PndEnDT, 'yyyy/mm/dd')) 
    OR ((a.Pend_Start_DT between TO_DATE (PndStDt, 'yyyy/mm/dd') and TO_DATE (PndEnDT, 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND a.Pend_End_DT is null));
```

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: In the 2nd scenario, if the end date is null, don't you just need to find records with `Pend_Start_DT <= PndStDt` and `Pend_End_DT is null`? No need to use `between`?

Comment: The error it returns is, "This operator must be followed by ANY or ALL".  If I simplify it down to this it works, but it's not accurate in what it needs to return: AND (a.Pend_Start_DT >= PndStDt and a.Pend_Start_DT <= PndEnDT);

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing `TO_DATE` and the parens are not in the correct place:

```
WHERE a.Audit_Status = '3'
AND
( 
   ( a.Pend_Start_DT    >= To_Date( PndStDt, 'yyyy/mm/dd' )
      AND a.Pend_End_DT <= To_Date( PndEnDT, 'yyyy/mm/dd' )
   )
   OR
   ( a.Pend_Start_DT BETWEEN To_Date( PndStDt, 'yyyy/mm/dd' ) 
      AND To_Date( PndEnDT, 'yyyy/mm/dd' )
      AND a.Pend_End_DT IS NULL
   ) 
)
```